# Removing elements with XPath

Tags: erlang, elixir

So let's say I have an XML file and I want to remove some nodes from it using their XPath. How would I do that and is it possible in the first place with `xmerl` or `erlsom` or maybe something else?

And if there is not a simple way with XPath, what is the correct way to remove elements from XML in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stated by W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/),

> XPath is a language for addressing parts of an XML document

the above literally means `XPath` is to *query* XML, not to *modify* it. The common approach to modifying XML document, would be to one of those:

- using XSLT transformation schema;
- reading the content into memory, modifying it and saving it back to the file.

AFAIU, the former is out of the scope of this question. For the latter, one might use [`Exsom` library](https://github.com/metalabdesign/exsom), which is “an Elixir wrapper around the `erlsom` XML parsing library.”

Assuming we have the `xml` and `xsd` taken from [`Excom` examples](https://github.com/metalabdesign/exsom/blob/master/test/examples):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo attr="yo">
  <bar>1</bar>
  <bar>2</bar>
</foo>
```

One might do something like this to delete second `bar` node (most of the code is taken as is from `Excom` tests:

```
{ :ok, model } = Exsom.XSD.File.parse("complex.xsd")
{ :ok, instance, _ } = Exsom.File.parse("complex.xml", model)
#⇒ {:ok, {:foo_type, [], 'yo', ['1', '2']}}
```

Modify it according to what you want, e.g. remove `bar` element with `2`

```
instance = {:foo_type, [], 'yo', ['1']}
{ :ok, binary_xml } = Exsom.compose(instance, model, [{ :output, :binary }])
#⇒ {:ok, "<foo attr=\"yo\"><bar>1</bar></foo>"}
```

Now you might write the `binary_xml` to a file.

Comment: Well my problem is that I have huge XML files and it's more complicated obviously so I can't just pattern match on the whole document and then write it back so I am figuring out a way to do properly

Comment: XSLT is the way to do it properly.

Comment: What is huge? In some ways the BEAM is remarkably memory efficient. Slurping entire docs into memory and working on them is often the fastest way to do things in Elixir.